# How to access SharePoint site in Linux using proxies in Python? I am successful using curl command

Tags: python, http, sharepoint, python-requests, urllib

I am try to establish connection to a SharePoint site from Python. To get the access token I m using "requests" module from python. I have set proxies in Linux Shell

```
export http_proxy=http://<user_name>:<Pass_word>@<proxy_server>:<proxy_port>
export https_proxy=https://<user_name>:<Pass_word>@<proxy_server>:<proxy_port>
```

I am successful by using CURL command but not from python script

Curl: (Curl is not working without proxy). I set proxy in Linux Shell.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/{TENANT_ID}/tokens/OAuth/2' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id={CLIENT_ID}@{TENANT_ID}' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret={CLIENT_SECRET}' \
--data-urlencode 'resource=00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/{tenant}.sharepoint.com@{TENANT_ID}'
```

Python Script:

```
import requests
from urllib.request import getproxies

def get_access_token():
    print(getproxies()) # To check whether I'm able to read proxies set in Linux Shell
    print(type(getproxies())) # <class 'dict'>
    
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    }
    body = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": "{CLIENT_ID}@{TENANT_ID}",
        "client_secret": "{CLIENT_SECRET}",
        "resource": "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/{tenant}.sharepoint.com@{TENANT_ID}",
    }
    _response = requests.post(
        "https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/{TENANT_ID}/tokens/OAuth/2",
        headers=headers,
        data=body,
        proxies=getproxies(), # I also tried not assigning proxies here as I set in Linux shell.   Both Failed
        allow_redirects=False, # I also tried allow_redirects=True. Both Failed
    )
    print("REQUEST: ", _response.content)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_access_token()
```

Error I am facing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/test_py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/opt/test_py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 72, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/opt/python_3.9.12/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 954, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/test_py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 700, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/opt/test_py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 994, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/opt/test_py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 358, in connect
    self.sock = conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/opt/test_py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f6c6b732be0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/test_py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/opt/test_py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/opt/test_py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /{tenant_id}/tokens/OAuth/2 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f6c6b732be0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/projadmin/faker_data/sharep/demo2.py", line 30, in <module>
    _response = requests.post(
  File "/opt/test_py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 117, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/test_py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/test_py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 529, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/opt/test_py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 645, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/test_py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 513, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /{tenant_id}/tokens/OAuth/2 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f6c6b732be0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')))
```

More Info: I am using requests==2.27.1, Python 3.9.12, Linux Centos7

I want how to make it working in Python when curl is successful.